# How to create docker image combining Spring boot app and python3 with libraries?

Tags: python-3.x, spring-boot, docker, numpy, opencv

all! I'm new to docker and I faced with problem how to combine Spring boot application with python 3 and it's libraries like opencv and numpy. I need it because my server uses python scripts to processing images.

I tried a lot of methods which I read here (in StackOverflow): I tried alpine and ubuntu as base images, I tried make a multistage build... Here's one of my attempts with ubuntu:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
RUN apt install openjdk-14-jre-headless
RUN apt install -y python3-pip
RUN apt install build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev python3-dev
RUN pip3 install numpy && pip3 intall opencv-python

EXPOSE 8080
COPY ./scripts ./scripts
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
ADD ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

And with another base image which consists of proper libraries:

```
FROM patavee/scipy-matplotlib-opencv-py3

FROM openjdk:14
EXPOSE 8080
COPY ./scripts ./scripts
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
ADD ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

What should I try next to success?

Comment: The first Dockerfile looks fine; the second is a multi-stage build that ignores the Python image (there's no way to combine two different images).  What problem are you running into, especially with the first image?

Comment: WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts. and E: Unable to locate package openjdk-14-jre-headless

Comment: But it's common package to Ubuntu

Comment: You need to `apt-get update` first, probably in the same `RUN` line as the `apt-get install`.

Comment: It works for me! But now I have some strange exceptions in server-side that I didn't have in my PC. But I think it is another problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

David Maze gave a really good advice: to add apt-get update to a first line.
So now Dockerfile changed like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
RUN apt-get update && apt install -y openjdk-14-jre-headless
RUN apt install -y python3-pip
RUN apt install -y build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev python3-dev
RUN pip3 install numpy && pip3 install opencv-python

EXPOSE 8080
COPY ./scripts ./scripts
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
ADD ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```